Why does an extra box render above my <div> element in CodeSandbox but not in VS Code?
I'm experiencing a strange issue where an extra box appears above my <div> element when running my code in CodeSandbox. However, when I run the same code locally in VS Code (using Live Server), it renders as expected without the extra box.
Here's the code I'm using:
<style>
  div {
    background: red;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 10px solid blue;
    margin: 10px;
  }
</style>
<div>texto</div>

Problem:
In CodeSandbox, two boxes are rendered: one with my intended styles and another empty one above it. This issue only happens when using <div>. For example, when I replace the <div> with a <p> or <span>, the problem disappears.
When I run the same code in VS Code (via Live Server or opening the file in a browser), it renders correctly without the extra box. I've attached a screenshot to demonstrate the issue in CodeSandbox.
What I've tried:

Changing the display property of the <div>.
Testing the code locally in VS Code (it works perfectly).
Using other tags like <p> and <span>, which don't produce the extra box.

